# I want a wordpress form to only show me one date per month

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datepicker

i am using youtr spectra(plugin) form with the date picker in gutenberg but i want to only have it show one date per month.

I tried this javascript code:

```
function custom_datepicker_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            // Specify the date you want to enable per month
            var enabledDate = "22/11/2023";

            // Disable the datepicker on the desired elements
            $(".uagb-forms-date-input[name='4f6b2f74']").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", date);
                    if (formattedDate === enabledDate) {
                        return [true, ""];
                    }
                    return [false, ""];
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

i am using wp code plugin which is like code snippets. This can add javascript to the specific page. For the class i used: uagb-forms-date-input[name=’4f6b2f74′] (without the dot) but i can get it to work. Can you show me how to do this?

The page I need help with: http://okwebsites.nl/6-2

i added javascript and the class to the block but it does not work. datepicker still shows me all dates.